# WebSharper - No javascript displaying in browser

Tags: f#, websharper

I have just started to play around with WebSharper an F# web framework. I have been trying the examples provided on Visual Studio but I have noticed that any of the functions annotated with `[<Javascript>]` do not appear om my browser.

I have checked that javascript is enabled and have checked it on different browsers(chrome, firefox and IE)

Any F#/WebSharper Guru explain what I am doing wrong or have I missed something?

Comment: can you give a example of one such function and how you checked? The easiest explanation I can come up with is that you used something that WebSharper could not *translate* into JS but you should get errors for those - What if you try the examples from the WebSharper-Homepage - do these work (just to check your browser)

Comment: What project type did you create in VS?

Comment: I created a Client-Server Web Application on VS 2012, I have tried the same template on VS 2013 and it works perfectly. I have read that VS 2012 need updates to the Nuget Packet Manager, so I am currently awaiting this to be installed by the I.T team as well as the latest VS update (Update 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If running in VS 2012, updates to the he Nuget Packet Manager as well as installing the latest update available, in my case(update 4) will solve this problem.

These updates can be found under Tools -> Extension and Updates -> Updates